# Secure random number generator

Tags: php, security, random, cryptography

I just wrote this function and I was curious if anyone could find any flaws in it.

It look pretty secure to me but I just want to make sure since I'm no cryptography expert.

```
function urandom_rand($min, $max) {

    if ($max <= $min) {
        trigger_error('Minimum value must be greater than maximum value.');
    }

    $maxHex = dechex($max);
    $maxHexLength = strlen($maxHex);
    $ivSize = (int)($maxHexLength + ($maxHexLength % 2)) / 2;
    // Reads bytes from /dev/urandom (or its Windows equivalent) - byte size is based on max value
    $r = hexdec(bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)));
    // Min/max modulo conversion to avoid using floats/round which is imprecise and prone to attacks
    $r = (($r - $min) % ($max - $min + 1) + ($max - $min + 1)) % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$max - $min` when calculating `$ivSize` and than basically add `$min`?

Comment: For `$min=0, $max=14` then `$s = (($r%15)+15)%15`. Since `$r>0` then `+15)%15` is useless, so `$s = $r%15`. For `$r in {0..254}`, `$s is in {0..14}` and for `$r=255` (the `$r` max), `$s=0`. The value 0 has one more chance to appear: *p(0)=18/256=7.03%* when others have *p(1,..,14)=`17/256`=6.64%*. Output is not equiprobable. Not sure how it can impact the security.

Comment: @TheConstructor Actually unless I misunderstood, $ivSize is in bytes so I'm converting $max into Hex, and then measuring the Hex's string length which something will omit the leading "0" (e.g. 0fff will be fff). So then I'm either adding 0 or 1 to the length depending if the length is odd or even. Then I divide by 2 to get the Byte size. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Xenos Very interesting finding... any suggestion on how to fix that? Not sure if it has any impact either but other options I found was using floats which I suspect would cause similar behavior due to the lack of precision of round()

Comment: You can use `$ivSize = ceil(log($max-$min, 0x100));`instead. `ceil(log(N,k))` counts how many digit `N` has in base `k` (byte is a 256-base where digits are 0..255)

Comment: There is probably no way to fix it at 100% because you have a set of N desired values (`$min..$max`) and you pick a random element from a `256^n` set: if they mismatch, you're in trouble. What you can do is pick a new `$r` as long as `$r >= floor((pow(0x100,$ivSize)-1)/($max-$min+1))*($max-$min))`, meaning *"as long as I'm too close to the iv upbound"* using a `do {} while()` structure. Weakness is that, theoretically, you can keep picking values for ever if you're very unlucky !

Comment: @Xenos your solution sound like it could fix the problem. I understand the weakness but I would be surprised to be unlucky forever? Would you mind answering back with what the code looks like? I'm not sure I understand exactly how to implement your suggestion. You're definitely stronger than I am in maths

Comment: @Xenos I tried to implement your solution but the result was a bit odd for the 2 first numbers. Basically the probability difference that was impacting p(0) was moved elsewhere. I decided to rethink the whole idea and came up with this completely modified code (posted in the answer). I've made tests up to 10 million and the probability seems to be the best I could find so far. It's still not perfect but I'm not sure if my Windows "urandom" is the culprit at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function urandom_rand($min = 0, $max = 0x7FFFFFFF)
{
    $min = (int)$min;
    $max = (int)$max;
    if ($max <= $min)
        trigger_error('Minimum value must be greater than maximum value.');
    if ($min < 0 || $max > 0x7FFFFFFF)
        trigger_error('Values must be between 0 and 2147483647.');

    $M = bcadd(0x7FFFFFFF,1); // (up bound of iv)+1
    $N = bcadd($max-$min, 1); // how many different values this function can return
    $h = bcmod($M, $N); // the last h integers from unpack are "invalids"

    do
    {
        $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $r = unpack("N", $bytes)[1] & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    } while ($r > ($M-$h));
    return (bcmod($r, $N) + $min);
}
```

Valid values for `$bytes` are

*0x00000000...0xffffffff*

After the `unpack()`, every value from `$bytes` is matching exactly one value of:

*-0x80000000..0x00000000..0x7ffffffff*

So, perfect-equiprobability. After bitwise `&`, every value from `unpack()` matches exactly two values of:

*0x00000000..0x7ffffffff*

Now, we cut that interval into `S` sub-intervals of `[KN..(K+1)N[` (*S>=1* because *$max<=0x7fffffff*) plus one remaining interval `I`. Then, we map each `[KN..(K+1)N[` to `[0..N-1]`.

So far, each value from `[0..N-1]` has exactly `S` ways to be picked.

Now, let's deal with the remaining interval `I` (might be an empty interval). If `$r` is in that interval, then we cannot do anything with it: we cannot easily match elements from `I` with elements from `[0..N-1]` because their size mismatch (`I` has less elements). We could group elements from `[0..N-1]` and then match these elements with `I` but that's far too complex for the earn.

So, if `$r` is in that remaining `I`, easy way is just to pick another `$r`.

Since `I` has `h = (0x7fffffff+1)%N` elements, that's why we keep picking random values as long as `$r > (0x7fffffff+1)-h`.

Only problem you can have is that the function `urandom_rand()` may take anytime to execute, since it loops until it luckily gets a `$r` outside `I`.

---

Here is one scenario of exploiting the inequiprobability problem:

Let's say you pick a random number out of `{0,1,...14}`, expecting a probability of `p(0)=P(1)=...=p(14)=1/15=6.67%`. People can bet on a number, and they will get `14.5x` their bet if they win (the `0.5x` remaining is your commission).

If you actually have `p(0)=7.03%` and `p(1)=..=p(14)=6.64%` then one can bet on 0 and expect 7.03% chances to win 14.5x their bet. So they averagely win `7.03%*14.5=1.01935`. Since it's greater than 1, you can keep betting forever and be a winner, despite the casino's commission.

There are probably similar *betting game* applied to cryptography.

---

Last correction to my comment about `ceil(log(N,k))` (I was tired yesterday night): correct formula is

`floor(log(N,k)+1)`

gives the number of digits of `N` in base `k` for `N integer and N>=1`

---

Without using bc function:

```
function urandom_rand($min = 0, $max = 0x7FFFFFFF)
{
    $min = (int)$min;
    $max = (int)$max;
    if ($max <= $min)
        trigger_error('Minimum value must be greater than maximum value.');
    if ($min < 0 || $max > 0x7FFFFFFF)
        trigger_error('Values must be between 0 and 2147483647.');

    // Decrease everything from 1st version by $N to avoid INT overflow
    // if min == 0 and max == 0x7fffffff then these M,N,h will overflow
    // BUT in such case, MNh won't be used (see loop below)
    // 1 <= $max - $min <= 0x7FFFFFFE
    $N = ($max - $min) + 1; // 2 <= $N <= 0x7FFFFFFF
    $M = (0x7FFFFFFF - $N) + 1; // 1 <= $M <= 0x7FFFFFFE
    $h = $M % $N; // 0 <= $h <= $N-1 <= 0x7FFFFFFE

    do
    {
        $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $r = unpack("N", $bytes)[1] & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        if ($min == 0 && $max == 0x7FFFFFFF)
            return $r; // direct corresponding
    } while (($r - $N) > ($M - $h));
    return (($r%$N)+$min);
}
```

Comment: Wow awesome - I just tested it and the $min / $max seems to have no impact on the return value. I'll see if I figure out why but it does look equiprobable

Comment: Ok I have no idea how to repair this.. I will most likely need your help to fix the $min / $max situation because all I can think of it add the modulo at the end but that would defeat the purpose of your fix :)

Comment: I managed to fix it using return $r %($max - $min + 1)+ $min; But I'm not sure this is the best approach?

Comment: You're right, I've focused on the proba and forgot to *map each [KN..(K+1)N[ to [0..N-1]* (iow, the ``return``). Your fix is OK for 2nd code, use ``bcmod`` for first one since ``$N`` (the ``$max - $min +1``) can be grater than ``0x7fffffff``.

Comment: Very cool work... much appreciated! By the way your last update returns value from [$min, $max+1]. This seems to solve it though but I'm sure you got a nicer implementation in mind: return bcmod($r, ($max - $min + 1)) + $min; Also I'm not sure, but what is the main different between the two versions?

Comment: Messy day ! ``$N = bcadd($max-$min, 1)``: there were an undesired ``+1``. There should be no difference from the outside. The only difference is that first requires ``bc*`` functions, when 2nd don't. ``BC Math`` extension is slower than native ``int`` calculus.

Comment: Well done! Everything works perfectly. I'll use the second option for sure now that I know that its faster. I owe you one... let me know if you need any help with anything!

Comment: Welcome ☺ You could make it even a bit faster by extracting ``$M, $N, $h`` out of the ``do...while`` loop.

Comment: Not sure I'm picturing it right now but by all means if you want to show me :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the edit - for some reasons I didn't get this was split from the main code... must have been tired this morning. I also added an iterator checker on my final version so that if it loops 1,000,000 time, it will write an error to the logs to ease troubleshooting. I doubt this will ever happen but just in case. Thanks again